# Parse string between <boolean> </boolean>

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to parse "true" from xml below with php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result2.xsd">

  <head>
    <link href="example2.rq" />
 </head>

  <boolean>true</boolean>

</sparql>
```

exactly the result is:

> true

i try to use:

```
$curl_response = curl_exec($curly);
curl_close($curly);
$result = new SimpleXMLElement($curl_response);
print_r($result);
echo $result->sparql->boolean;
```

but it can't work. Is there any way to get the "true" from that xml and parse it to new variable?

Answer (score 3):

No, you're already at the parent start point, no need to add `->sparql`:

```
$result = new SimpleXMLElement($curl_response);
$boolean = $result->boolean;
echo $boolean;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2jorPh)